# Prove that a metrizable space is countably compact iff it is compact.

Tags: general-topology, metric-spaces, compactness

Prove that a metrizable space is countably compact iff it is compact.

($\Rightarrow$)

I let $\{O_i\}$ be a countable open cover for $(X,T)$ with a finite subcover.  Let $\{U_i\}$ be an uncountable open cover (because otherwise it's countable and then trivial).  From here I'm stuck.  I figure that I can add an uncountable number of additional open balls to the countable set to make in an uncountable set or select a countable subset of the uncountable set, but I'm not sure how I'd do this.  To prove this without sequential compactness is what I'm looking for.

Comment: Possible duplicate: http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/431146/prove-that-a-metric-space-is-countably-compact-if-and-only-if-every-infinite-seq

Comment: I'm trying to prove this without knowing anything about sequential compactness.

Comment: But in  metric space sequential compactness and compactness are equivalent. Or do you mean that you have not learned about sequential compactness yet?

Comment: Yes, I want to try to prove this given that I have not learned about sequential compactness yet.  Sequential compactness is the next type of compactness I'll be learning about in the book I'm reading, but I want to prove this without skipping ahead.

Answer (score 6):

I don’t know a direct argument along the lines that you’ve tried to start. I would prove it in steps, as follows.

- Show that if $X$ is countably compact, then $X$ does not have an infinite, closed, discrete subset.
- Show that for each $n\in\Bbb Z^+$ there is a finite $F_n\subseteq X$ such that $\left\{B\left(x,\frac1n\right):x\in F_n\right\}$ covers $X$.
- Show that $\left\{B\left(x,\frac1n\right):n\in\Bbb Z^+\text{ and }x\in F_n\right\}$ is a countable open base for $X$.
- Prove that in fact every open cover of $X$ has a countable subcover (i.e., $X$ is Lindelöf).
- Conclude that $X$ is compact.

I’ll leave it at that for now in case you’d like to try to fill in the details.

Comment: I don’t suppose that the downvoter would care actually to be helpful and explain what problem he or she perceives here?